# Swift + Xcode 6: What method is called when storyboard segue is performed

Tags: uiviewcontroller, storyboard, swift, segue

I am creating my first app with storyboards. So far, I have two ViewControllers - on the first VC, the user taps a button, and it takes them to the second VC, using a 'Present modally" segue.

Is there some method that is called when the new view appears? I want to be able to write the code to start the game in here.

Comment: A view controller always has the same life-cycle, regardless of whether or not it was presented via a segue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at `viewDidLoad()`, `viewWillAppear(_:)` and `viewDidAppear(_:)`. Most likely what you need is the first one.

Comment: This doesn't work - all the methods are called when the apps starts up, but not when the user taps the button and goes to the second VC, which is the exact opposite of what I want it to do.

Comment: If you want to perform some processing when the 2nd VC is shown, then you have to override in that class, not in the 1st. Otherwise I'm afraid I haven't caught what you mean

Comment: Sorry, I'm super inexperienced with all this! I only have one ViewController.swift file, and one storyboard. Inside that storyboard, I have two viewControllers. Is this the correct thing to do?

Comment: when you want to respond to view appearance methods for the second viewController, you'll have to create a new subclass of UIViewController for this second one and override the method mentioned by @Antonio in that class

Comment: You should create another source file for the 2nd view controller. I think it's better if you take a look at [raywenderlich.com tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/74438) (series of 3), then look for other tutorials - even if they use objective-c.

Comment: I got there eventually! Thank you all!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're searching for the `prepareForSegue` method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "Load View") {
        // pass data to next view
    }
}
```

It's called right before the segue is performed so you can for example identify the target ViewController and pass it some params.